# Updating values and saving them in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I am very new to redux and still trying to get my feet wet with it. I am working on a mini application that fetches data from an endpoint and renders the items. The user then has the ability to "pin" these items and this is the part I am not sure about.

In my actions, I have the logic set for getting the data

```
import {FETCH_POST} from './types';

export function fetchPost() {
    console.log('fetch..');
    return function (dispatch) {
        fetch('https://someapi/.json?count=20')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(posts =>
                dispatch({
                    type: FETCH_POST,
                    payload: posts.data.children
                })
            )
        ;
    }
}
```

My reducer has the condition to handle this action

```
import {FETCH_POST} from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
    items: [],
    item: {}
};

export default function(state = initialState, action){
    switch (action.type){
        case FETCH_POST:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {items: action.payload});
        default:
            return state;
    }

}

//Main reducer file

import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import postReducer from './postReducer';

export default combineReducers({
   post: postReducer
});
```

Here is my component

```
class Post extends Component{
    componentWillMount(){
        this.props.fetchPost();
    }

    pinPost(){
       //...not sure how to update here
    }

    render(){
        const postItems = this.props.posts.map(post => (
            <div key={post.data.id} className="listBox">
                <div className="listContent">
                    <i className="fa fa-thumb-tack pin" onClick={this.pinPost}></i>
                    <a href={'https://someapi' + post.data.permalink} target="_blank">{post.data.title}</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        ));

        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Pinned</h1>
                <hr/>
                <h1>Posts</h1>
                {postItems}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

My objective here, is to have an ability to pin the posts by clicking on the icon and then show that post under the "Pinned" section rather than the "Posts" section.

The `this.props.posts` array consists of objects which have an property of `pinned: false` by default, along with other properties tied to it. I would want this to be set to 'true' if pinned and reset to 'false' if unpinned.

How would I go about this? Would I need another action to handle this?

Comment: Looks like you're using redux-thunk?

Comment: @TrueWill yes I came across that in a tutorial, part of the boilerplate while setting up redux

Comment: do you want this pin to change the data on the server? Or only client side?

Comment: on the client side because I plan on using localstorage for pinned items to persist data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is, first you need to update the pinned property of particular post in redux store onClick of pin button. To do that you need to bind the unique property (post id) with onClick method and dispatch an action with that id.

**Steps:**

**1-** Pass the unique id of each post to pinPost method:

```
onClick={this.pinPost.bind(this, post.data.id)}
```

**2-** Dispatch the action to update the `pinned` property of that post in redux store:

```
pinPost(id) {
   this.props.updatePost(id)
}
```

**3-** Define updatePost as:

```
updatePost(id) {
    dispatch({
        type: 'UPDATE_POST',
        id,
    })
}
```

**4-** Now inside reducer update the `pinned` property of that post:

```
export default function(state = initialState, action){
    switch (action.type){
        case FETCH_POST:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {items: action.payload});
        case UPDATE_POST:
            const items = state.items.map(el => el.data.id == action.id ? 
                {data: Object.assign({}, el.data, { pinned: true })} : el
            return Object.assign({}, state, { items })
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

**5-** Now render the element in different section:

```
render(){
    let pinnedPost = [], postItems = []
    this.props.posts.forEach(post => {
        if(post.data.pinned) {
            pinnedPost.push(
                <div key={post.data.id} className="listBox">
                    <div className="listContent">
                        <i className="fa fa-thumb-tack pin"></i>
                        <a href={'https://someapi' + post.data.permalink} target="_blank">{post.data.title}</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        } else {
            postItems.push(
                <div key={post.data.id} className="listBox">
                    <div className="listContent">
                        <i className="fa fa-thumb-tack pin" onClick={this.pinPost}></i>
                        <a href={'https://someapi' + post.data.permalink} target="_blank">{post.data.title}</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        }

    ));

    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Pinned</h1>
            {pinnedPost}
            <hr/>
            <h1>Posts</h1>
            {postItems}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: what if I also wanted to unpin the post, would it require a new action?

Comment: you can have a separate function for that, but better approach will be to use same function for both type of action, along with the id also pass the value `true/false` in the dispatch action and set the `pinned: value` instead of doing `pinned:true` :)